# React Component renders to screen before redirecting instead of after redirecting

Tags: reactjs

I have a logout menu which upon clicking logout  calls  Component and redirects page to /logout.

I want to render a MSLogin div after the page is redirected to /logout screen but instead the div is being rendered right before redirecting the page.

How can I achieve the intended result ? Please some one can help me solve this?

```
export function AccountMenu(props){
const [renderMSLogin, setMSLogin] = useState(false);

<div>
<a href='/api/auth/logout' className='list-item logout'
          onClick={()=>setMSLogin(!renderMSLogin)} >logout</a>
</div>

{renderMSLogin ? <Logout /> : null}
}
```

This is my Logout Component

```
export function Logout() {
    return(
        
            <MSLogin/>
        
        );
    }
```

And this is my MSLgin component

```
export function MSLogin(){

    return(
        <div className='login'>
            <div className='login-container'>
                <div className='login-box'>
                    <div className='welcome-text'>{'Welcome'}</div>
                    <a className='sign-in-link' href='/api/auth/login'>
                        <img src={mslogin} className="ms-img" alt="Microsoft" />
                        {'Sign in with Microsoft'}
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div className='spacer' />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: your `onClick` listener changing renderMSLogin to true and Logout is rendering immediatley `{renderMSLogin ? <Logout /> : null}
}`, what is '/api/auth/logout', app route or an api ?

Comment: @NageshSanika /api/auth/logout is an app route. Should I be adding some time interval before rendering Logout {renderMSLogin ? <Logout/> : null} . If yes how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `history.push()` to navigate between 2 pages in React js. Try this:

In `AccountMenu.js`:

```js
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

const AccountMenu = ({history}) => {
  handleOnClick = () => {
    history.push('/api/auth/logout')
  }
    
  return <div className='list-item logout' onClick={handleOnClick} >logout</div>
}

export default withRouter(AccountMenu)
```

In `App.js`:

```js
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import Logoutfrom 'path_to_Logout.js'

const App = () => {
  ...
  return (
    <Switch>
      ...
      <Route path='/api/auth/logout' component={Logout} />
      ...
    </Switch>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Here is the change I had to make to get this working .
Edititon to AccountMenu component : 

```
function handleLogout()
  {
   
    history.push("/api/auth/logout");
  }

<div className='list-item logout' onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</div>
```
Edition to Logout Component 
```
export function Logout () {
    const [, setHeaderTitle] = useContext(HeaderContext);
    return(
        
        <div>
             <MSLogin/>
        </div>
      
        );
    }
    ```
And added Logout Component to <Route path /> in App.js